# Filtering on columns partitioning on unique id without duplicates

Tags: sql, aggregation

I am trying to create a rule to filter on events based on a partition, and I am trying to do it in a better way than the one I am doing:

I have the following events table:

```sql
EVENT_ID,USER_PROPERTIES_KEY,USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE
1,country,us
1,country_id,fr
2,country,uk
3,country_id,it
4,platform,Android
4,country,cn
```

The objective is to add a column country_code, based on the following rule:

If for the same event_id, USER_PROPERTIES_KEY = country and USER_PROPERTIES_KEY = country_id, country_code will take USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE, where USER_PROPERTIES_KEY = country_id, for EVENT_ID = 1, it will be 'fr', otherwise it takes USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE of USER_PROPERTIES_KEY of the event_id, else if none of the country, and country_id are respected, it takes null.

The final expected result would be:

```sql
EVENT_ID,USER_PROPERTIES_KEY,USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE,COUNTRY_CODE
1,country_id,fr,fr
2,country,uk,uk
3,country_id,it,it
4,platform,Android,null
4,country,cn,cn
```

I have to partition on the EVENT_ID following that query and filter on 'NA', but I am not able to do that.

```sql
select
    EVENT_ID,
    USER_PROPERTIES_KEY,
    USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE,
    CASE
        WHEN USER_PROPERTIES_KEY like 'country%' THEN
       CASE WHEN count(user_properties_key like 'country%') over(partition by EVENT_ID) > 1
            THEN
            CASE
                WHEN user_properties_key = 'country_id'
                THEN UPPER(user_properties_value) ELSE 'NA'
            END
        WHEN count(user_properties_key like 'country%') over(partition by EVENT_ID) = 1
                THEN UPPER(user_properties_value) ELSE 'NA'
            END
        END
    AS country_code
from events;
```

Comment: I see no 'sa' in sample data. Also 'otherwise it takes USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE of USER_PROPERTIES_KEY of the event_id' is not clear, multiple rows exist for an  `event_id`. Please correct.

Comment: sorry, it must be 'fr' not 'sa'. Also, the event_id is duplicated, because these key values are coming from a flattened json. and the objective is to add the new country_code column respecting the conditions mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `first_value` ordered by the priority requested. Also you can flag the rows you want with `case` and `row_number`

```
select
    EVENT_ID,
    USER_PROPERTIES_KEY,
    USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE,
    country_code
from (
  select
    EVENT_ID,
    USER_PROPERTIES_KEY,
    USER_PROPERTIES_VALUE,
    case when USER_PROPERTIES_KEY like 'country%' then
        row_number()over(partition by EVENT_ID order by case USER_PROPERTIES_KEY when 'country_id' then 1 when 'country' then 2 else 3 end)
      else 1 end flag,   
    first_value(case when USER_PROPERTIES_KEY like 'country%' THEN UPPER(user_properties_value) END)
          over(partition by EVENT_ID order by case USER_PROPERTIES_KEY when 'country_id' then 1 when 'country' then 2 else 3 end)
       AS country_code
  from events
) t
where flag = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=54cf0a5bf834e580adc567dc8e2b59ce)

Comment: I tried that, and indeed it gives the good country_code, but I want to get rid of the duplicates on USER_PROPERTIES_KEY, so for the same event_id, we should not have 2 records having country and country_id for USER_PROPERTIES_KEY column. thanks for your help. My bad, I didn't add the correct expected values, I have modified it. And for the case where it's not country, or coutry_id (platform in this case), it has to be null.

Comment: @dnej, please edit the question to include all essential rules, don't hide it in comments.

Comment: I have updated the expected value. Sorry for that.

Comment: @dnej,  see the edited version

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for indeed. I just modified the second partition by from EVENT_ID to USER_PROPERTIES_KEY, to have null values when USER_PROPERTIES_KEY is different from country and country_id. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Actually when I did that, I don't have the expected result. Is there anyway we can apply the country code only on USER_PROPERTIES_KEY = country or country_id ? thanks

Comment: @dnej, sample data and the desired result in the question would help.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it works good, the only issue that I have on large dataset is performance. is there any way to improve it ?